# Can I load a page with an HTML 5 Doctype into a frame on a page with a Frameset Doctype?

Tags: javascript, html, doctype, frames

I have a main frameset page, which uses the FRAMESET doctype..Now this has 3 frames inside it..

Now for the 2nd frame, I want to use some HTML5 code ()...So guess I'll have to use the doctype

Now my question is; can both these doctypes co-exist, which means can I declare FRAMESET doctype for the main frameset page and HTML5 Doctype for one of the frame page..

Can it cause any cross-browser issues?
Also before you say, I know this is a strange question as I am using old/outdated frameset with the latest HTML5...But I have limited options (In fact, can't edit the main frameset page to use iframes)...So want to know how can I combine the 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctypes are specific to documents and each document has its own independent doctype. Having a different doctype in each frame is perfectly valid, and having the doctype of the frameset be different from the doctype of the frames is not only valid, it's impossible for it to be otherwise. Whether it's HTML 5 doesn't really enter into it.

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is; can both these doctypes co-exist, which means can I declare FRAMESET doctype for the main frameset page and HTML5 Doctype for one of the frame page..

They are separate, independent documents, so: **yes**.

Comment: Ok..Thx a lot..Just a follow-up question...If I use HTML5 elements like <audio>, is it absolutely necessary to specify <!DOCTYPE html> ...I mean can it kind of run in quirks and understand somehow..

Comment: If you don't have the right Doctype, then validation will throw up a pile of errors which you'll have to dig through to find any errors that could cause you problems.

Comment: @hmthr regarding your question "is it absolutely necessary to specify <!DOCTYPE html>" this doctype has backward compatibility to all the previous doctypes and html versions. so i recommend you use this. safer for your html5 markup validation

Comment: Ok..The only reason i am hesitating to use the html5 doctype on my page is bcoz apart from html5 elements like audio, it uses old and some deprecated tags also..so if i use html5 doctype, will those old tags render on the browser correctly ?

Comment: @hmthr it will render in the browsers that support these deprecated tags. 
HTML5 is backwards-compatible (read about here [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#backwards-compatible)  ) 
Here is a list of [deprecated](http://www.webbyzone.com/2011/02/27/deprecated-tags-in-html5) elements and its replacements

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the answer is no because as usual, Internet Explorer. This link: http://css-tricks.com/ie-iframe-quirksmode/ is validating my findings that my html5 document loaded inside of a frame loaded inside of a much older parent document with frameset doctype is rendering in quirksmode because "In IE, iFrames on Pages in Quirks Mode Also in Quirks Mode". It sounds like this is the case with Frames as well as IFrames even in IE11.